# Do Distributor Caps need Regular Replacement?

Tags: ignition

Does the rotor physically contact the points in a distributor cap and cause them to wear down such that the cap would need replacement at regular intervals?

Comment: For clarification, the points do not physically contact the rotor arm during rotation.  The points are on the low tension (LT) side of the ignition system whilst the rotor arm and distributor cap on on the high tension (HT) side of the system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only physical connection is the center electrode which is usually carbon based.  The other electrodes that connect to the plug leads don't touch the rotor arm, but come very close allowing the spark to jump across the gap without too much loss of power.  Each time the spark jumps, however, a small chemical reaction will take place on the terminals which causes the build up of 'corrosion' or oxidation.  This can be scraped off occasionally but eventually the terminals will be eaten away and the cap will require replacement.

As time goes on the gaps get wider and the spark will get slightly weaker at each spark plug.

Comment: @Ducatikiller Thanks for the edit.  I wasn't sure whether it was oxidisation, or whether it was some other compound that was being formed.